# Will this method make sha256 harder to crack?

Tags: java, hashalgorithm

Will this method make sha256 harder to crack?

```
 public byte[] hash(String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
     MessageDigest sha256 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
     byte[] passBytes = password.getBytes();
     byte[] passHash = sha256.digest(passBytes);
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         passHash = sha256.digest(passHash);
     }
     return passHash;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have there is called key stretching and it will make the SHA harder to crack. The basic process is to slightly increase the work that the server does in order to massively increase the work that any attacker must do.

This is effective because the server is deriving the hash from a known plaintext input, while the attacker is making many many guesses at what the plaintext must be. This means that the server stretches the key once while the attacker must do it many times.

You can read more about this technique [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching). Some hashing algorithms, such as bcrypt, are always assumed to involve multiple rounds like this.

Answer (score 1):

SHA-256 is an irreversible one-way cryptographic hash function. Applying that hash 10 times does not *create* any additional security, although it does make a typical rainbow attack more difficult (but using a [Salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) would have the same advantage). Your hashing mechanism has a fairly substantial disadvantage in that it takes 10 times as long to run.

Comment: But if the attacker bruteforces and gets the key that produced the hash, then he must bruteforce 10 times in order to get the first key?

Comment: You seem to be conflating rainbow tables (a mechanism which could easily be used to attack your 10-fold SHA-256) and reversible cryptography. A [hash collision](https://bitcointalk.org/?topic=191.0) is not necessarily the same as the initial key, but it can be used in place of the correct key.